# passing an instance into a method in c#

Tags: c#, methods, instance

so ive been doing this assignment all night now and I think ive gone completely wrong on one part. this is the section im stuck on:

1. TableOrder class will carry two methods for adding items from the menu: 
   AddFood(), AddDrink(). Each method will pass in a prepared instance of 
   either the FoodItem or DrinkItem class you previously created.                                                                  It is expected that the order system will maintain a separate collection 
   of drinks from food given that we will be passing the drinks orders to 
   bar staff and likewise food orders to the kitchen.

I have previously created two classes to for FoodItem and DrinkItem but am struggling to grasp the concept of what the question is asking. Please help!

hopefully somebody can explain what it is i am doin wrong. this is the code i have so far...

```
List<DrinkItem> DrinkMenu = new List<DrinkItem>();

public DrinkItem AddDrink(DrinkItem drinkItem)
    {
        return drinkItem;
    }

    public List<DrinkItem> OrderedDrink
    {
        get
        {
            return DrinkMenu;
        }
    }
```

the next section is as follows:

1. The TableOrder class provides two separate properties given below, each of which returns a copy of the stored items. Each are expected to return an instance of the List class where T is the appropriate class. It is not expected that I can set these food and drink using these properties.
   a. OrderedFood
   b. OrderedDrink.

i have ammended the first section and it works, but it has now given me errors on my 2nd part... any ideas as to why this might have happened?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, why not create separate lists for DrinkItem and FoodItem and keep adding items in each separate methods. Like `DrinkMenu.Add(drinkItem);`

Comment: `It is expected that the order system will maintain a separate collection of drinks from food` - this implies you need to maintain 2 collections. AddDrink should add it to the drinks collection and AddFood should add to the Food collection

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try to give you some ideas.

First of all you need to have a `TableOrder` class

```
public class TableOrder
{

}
```

Responsibility of the class is: `class will carry two methods for adding items from the menu`

So, you create two methods in the class who will add things to the order list:

```
public void AddFood()
{
}

public void AddDrink()
{
}
```

You also need order list and according to the requirement you need two order lists one for food and another for drink. So, you put two fields in the class like,

```
private List<FoodItem> FoodOrders = new List<FoodItem>();
private List<DrinkItem> DrinkOrders = new List<DrinkItem>();
```

In the method you just pass items and add them to this list

```
public void AddFood(FoodItem fo)
{
    FoodOrders.Add(fo);
}

public void AddDrink(DrinkItem do)
{
    DrinkOrders.Add(do);
}
```

And while you are using `TableOrder` you just need to call these methods to add orders like,

```
tableOrder.AddDrink(drinkItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand this the `AddDrink` Method should add the Drink to the `OrderedDrink` List eachtime a Drink is ordered:

```
public DrinkItem AddDrink(DrinkItem drinkItem)
{
    OrderedDrink.Add(drinkItem);
    return drinkItem;
}
```

And if the return value is not needed you may consider declaring the Method as `void`.

Important would also be to empty the `OrderedDrink` List eachtime its passed to the kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to write a `class TableOrder` which contains two collections. One for storing the ordered `DrinkItems`s and one for storing the ordered `FoodItem`s. This `class` should provide two methods:

1. `AddDrink` which gets passed a `DrinkItem` and adds it to the other drinks stored in your collection
2. `AddFood` which gets passed a `FoodItem` and adds it to the collection of ordered foods

In general a method which only returns its parameter without doing anything else like you have written for `AddDrink` is completely useless so this is an quick and easy check if what you wrote can be right.